# How to use Wix msi to selectively install MSI

Tags: wix, installation, chained

How can i use Wix to check a registry setting, and depending on that value, select the correct MSI from 2 MSIs to install? The registry entry denotes x86 or x64.  If x64, the Wix installer should then installed the 64 bit Msi.  If x86, it should install 32 bit version.

I tried this, but I just get an error on install that says

"This installation package could not be opened.  Contact the vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

Both "chained" MSIs function correctly by themselves.

This is a file Bundle.wxs and is the only file in the Wix project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

  <Bundle Name="SingleInstaller" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="935daa4e-9b25-4fef-a4a1-0cf6af71a939">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>

    <!--Search the registry entries for each because it may be under Wow6432-->
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\SomeEntry\" Value="Bitness" Variable="MyRegEntry" Win64="no" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\SomeEntry\" Value="Bitness" Variable="MyRegEntry" Win64="yes" />

    <Chain>
      <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
      <!--<MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\Dev\Cwds_Install\bin\x86\Release\JMPS-CC-CWDS3.0.0.0.msi" InstallCondition="Jmps32Bit = x86" Id="Cwds32"/>-->
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:MyProgram.msi" InstallCondition="MyRegEntry = x86" Id="MyProgram32" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:MyProgram.msi" InstallCondition="MyRegEntry = x64" Id="MyProgram64" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Hello Red Baron 2.0. Did you look at the 64-bit specific built-in variables: [Burn Built-in Variables](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html). For example `System64Folder` or `VersionNT64` - these are supposedly undefined on x86-systems. `System64Folder` (64-bit) and `NOT System64Folder` (32-bit) should work?

Comment: Thank you for recognizing the red baron.

Comment: But how would i selectively install the msi ?  The decision of which msi to install is based upon a registry entry of a 3rd party application.  I know how to read this entry already.  I just want to know how to act on that variable i will set, and then run the correct "child" msi

Comment: Bundle .exes create log files in %TMP% that will show what happens when Burn runs the package.

Comment: I don't see any log file there after running the msi if thats what you mean

Comment: Apparently Bundle can only do exes?